# What is the difference in using forward and reverse iterators in find_if

Tags: c++, stl

I have two functions (an example from a book):

```
std::string trim_right(std::string s)
{
    s.erase(std::find_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), isalpha).base(),s.end() );

    return s;
} 
std::string trim_left(std::string s)
{
    s.erase(s.begin(),
        std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), isalpha));
    return s;
}
```

Why in function `trim_right` with reverse iterators I need to use `base()`, but in `trim_left` with forward iterators I don't need it ?

Comment: Because `string`s `erase()` has overloads accepting `iterator` and (since C++11) `const_iterator`,  not for `reverse_iterator` and `const_reverse_iterator`.  Reverse iterators are implemented in terms of the "underlying" iterator, and their `base()` member gives access to that underlying iterator (e.g. obtains a corresponding `iterator` from a `reverse_iterator`).

Answer (score 0):

Reverse iterators are adapters on regular iterators. And `erase` overloads accept only the regular, non-reverse, `iterator` and `const_iterator`. What `reverse_it.base()` does is unwrap the adapted iterator inside `reverse_iterator`. So it is a way to get `iterator` from `reverse_iterator` or `const_iterator` from `const_reverse_iterator`.